# how to solve? Expected identifier or '('?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to create a cancel code to webView coming back with other website information. So i am first trying to create the delegate, but i keep getting the following error.

Expected identifier or '('

The error is placed below.

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize webView;

{                                             // Expected identifier or '('

(webView.delegate = nil)

}


- (void)viewDidLoad


{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://twitter.com/u_bett"];

    NSURLRequest *urlrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webView loadRequest:urlrequest];
```

Comment: Please spend some time with some good, up-to-date, Objective-C tutorials. You need to learn the basics of the language before you can write an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
{                                             // Expected identifier or '('

(webView.delegate = nil)

}
```

Is in the middle of nowhere, it should be inside a method.

What are you trying to achieve?

edited after the comments:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad


{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webView.delegate = nil;
```

Comment: Im new with coding. Im trying to disable return request within a webView.

Comment: i just completed this code following the delegate request. :(webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationtype:return NO);

Comment: I dont understand what you mean with disable return request within a webView, can you explain morE?

Comment: So i have created a webView for an app i am creating. So the forward back button are failed to work. So my partner and i decided to disable the navigation of viewers. This only allowing them to navigate the homepage. If they click anywhere else possibly leaving the homepage it is disabled and they can not do that. In order to make the navigation disabled i must change the delegate to nil.

Comment: and making the delegate nil is what i am trying to do right now.

Comment: Put this on the viewDidLoad then webView.delegate = nil;

Comment: i did this. and another error appeared that says: use of undeclared identifier 'delegate'. What would this solution be?